# How to add an expression as a superscript in notion?

Tags: notion-api

I am new to notion I have been previously using OneNote.
Can anyone please tell how you write expressions as a superscript in notion?

I understand how to write superscripts in notion which is basically
/inline equation and then just c^x

But what if I have to let say write
e^(3x) how will I do that using brackets seems not to work

Thanks already!

Comment: I figured it out apparently you are supposed to use curly brackets {}. 
For example e^{3x}

Answer (score 1):

Notion equations use KaTex formatting. To format multiple characters in superscript, simply wrap them in `{}` symbols!

Example:

`e ^ {.3 * 10}`

[Here's the KaTex function reference](https://katex.org/docs/supported.html).